# css hover state becomes inactive after click

Tags: jquery, css, click, hover

On this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3x7M/), after clicking one of the boxes the hover state becomes inactive and doesn't show up again.

I have three boxes with background set using css `background-image`. I'm using jQuery to attach a click event. Can you help me identifying why the hover state stop workgin?

Thanks.

Comment: `why is my hover state inactive after i click one of the image`  >>why do you have two click events for the same element

Comment: Nothing happens on hover for it to be overturned. what do you mean?

Comment: @bipen i don't know how to merge that two click events

Answer (score 3):

When jQuery changes the background image, it does so `inline`, as in it modifies the actual HTML. That means the new background image is more [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the one set in the `#one:hover` so it can't override it.

You need to add `!important` after each new background image on `:hover` to make sure it has the specificity to overwrite it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J3x7M/3/)

Comment: And this is why it is generally smarter to not set CSS values directly, but uses classes or similar instead. Also helps the separation of logic and formatting.

Comment: @andy there are 3 conditions in each of the image. Idle, hover and clicked. When we added !important to css, the clicked state shows only on mouseout. I want it to be shown right after we click the image. Any other idea to solve this? thanks by the way

Comment: @user2432458 Then what I would suggest is instead of changing the image of the element each time, just add in and remove classes such as `.clicked` which have `background-image: url()`

Answer (score 2):

Because inline styles for li overwrites your css :hover selectors properties.
Use `!important` to make it work:

```
li#one:hover{
    background-image: url(http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a628/botpro7/1_hover_zps6b4b99c1.png)!important;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. the clicked state shows only on mouseout. it supposed to be shown after we click the image. any idea? thanks.

Comment: Its because you use images, use text and change properties as color and margin on hover and active states. It would be better this way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you was getting was because you was setting the background inline with css property with jquery, i have made a demo which solves your problem.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J3x7M/4/)

I removed the part of code which was inserting the background, and just added a `.active` class to your code, so when the user click on the element, i set that class on the element.
I hope you enjoy!

Comment: @ Wallysson Nunes. thanks for the answer. how can i show the clicked-state image? the number supposed to be at the bottom after we click.

Comment: That's no problem, i've changed the code, here's the new example: http://jsfiddle.net/J3x7M/5/ 

The basic thing that i did was split the .active class on new classes with your needed image, which was with bottom number. Hope that help... :)

Comment: @ Wallysson Nunes. Thank you nunes! what a great and simple script.